# My JavaScript random number is always initialized to 1?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me troubleshoot this? In the below code, `circx` and `circy` are being initialized appropriately, but `theta` is always initializing to 1! The console logs `theta = 1` every time I load the page.

```
var circx = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE) % papwidth;
var circy = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE) % papheight;
/*
    circx, circy: initial positions of circle on the papern
*/
var mycirc = paper.circle(circx, circy, 10);
mycirc.attr("fill","#F9C624");
var theta = Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE) % 4 + 1; 
/*
    theta = 1 <---> object moving at a 45-degree angle
    theta = 2 <---> object moving at a 135-degree angle
    theta = 3 <---> object moving at a 225-degree angle
    theta = 4 <---> object moving at a 315 degree angle
*/

console.log("theta = " + theta);
```

This makes no sense!

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either - clearly the result should be 4, not 1. http://xkcd.com/221

Answer (score 7):

```
> Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE
8.365923028455995e+307
```

You see that `e+307`? That means it ends in 307 zeroes. Doubles are not stored in integer precision. Take that mod 4 and add 1, and you always get 1. (Or you do 99.99999...% of the time).

Answer (score 4):

```
var theta = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
```

Should just works fine.

**Addendum:**

As [Tom Fenech](/users/2088135/tom-fenech) pointed out, [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) produces a number from 0 (incl.) to 1 (excl.), which allows for a more intuitive solution:

```
var theta = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
```

Comment: (There was a preceeding comment asking whether I'm sure not to use `random() * 4`) Yeah, pretty sure: `random()` will give you a number [0..1]. Multiply that by 3, and you'll get [0..3]. user3537336 asked for a number [1..4], so you'll add 1. To get a number from the set [1,2,3,4], you'll simply round the result.

Comment: I was just looking at [Math.random() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and it says that the range is 0 inclusive to 1 exclusive. Perhaps you could just use `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4)`

Comment: That should work as well. I'll update my answer, thanks.